# Javascript: Slice / Trim array from range that contains float numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an number array which contains floats, I've tried to use slice but with no luck as it does not work on float numbers (or I am doing something wrong here)

```
var array = [1.5, 1.7, 2.05, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.8, 3.3, 3.4, 3.59, 3.68, 3.9, 4, 4.1, 32, 33.6, 35, 39, 41.7, 42.88, 49, 53.09, 56, 59, 59, 69, 99, 129, 169, 169, 189, 229, 256.2]
```

Slice returns only a empty array

```
> array.slice(60, 250)
> []
```

---

Basically i want to get all numbers in range between 60, 250.

Comment: Use `filter`. `arr.filter(num => num >= 60 && num <= 250)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes items from start index up to an end index, and returns a new array. Since your array doesn't have 60 items or more (indexes 60 to 250), it returns an empty array.

To remove items from an array using a condition on the value (between 60 and 250 for example), you can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var array = [1.5, 1.7, 2.05, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.8, 3.3, 3.4, 3.59, 3.68, 3.9, 4, 4.1, 32, 33.6, 35, 39, 41.7, 42.88, 49, 53.09, 56, 59, 59, 69, 99, 129, 169, 169, 189, 229, 256.2];

var result = array.filter(function(n) {
  return n >= 60 && n <=250;
});

console.log(result);
```